# How do I get a custom javadoc tag to appear in the autocomplete javadoc in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I've added a custom tag of @modifies in the build section of the properties as follows:

-tag modifies:a:"This method modifies: "

This only shows up when I click 'generate javadoc' not when I am looking at the method in netbeans where I get the window that shows me all of the parameters the method takes and the other javadoc stuff.

EDIT: To be clear, this is not annotation related. Annotations are outside of the javadoc comment and are used at runtime and compile time, tags are only used by the javadoc generator.

Comment: The argument is -tag though, and all over the sun/oracle docs it calls them tags. I believe annotations to be used by the compiler and stored for use after compilation. Tags are for generating javadocs. See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up wrapping our javadoc tags in html/bold so that it looked similar to the existing javadoc comments. It came out close enough that they looked the same.